# Rechargeable Powers

Tags: dnd-4e

Many monsters have rechargeable powers/attacks. How do you know when those are recharged? The most common one I have seen is 5 6. I'm guessing this does not mean 56 turns. I believe in the monsters manual 1 or 2 these are represented by a 5 and 6 rolled on 6 sided dice. does this mean I need to roll an 11 or 12 on  a pare of 6 sided dice or what?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Recharge 5,6" means that you roll 1d6 at the start of each round, and if a 5 or 6 comes up, the power has recharged adn can be used again on that round.

Comment: Are there any creatures that don't use a d6?

Comment: Its always a D6 for rechargeable powers.