# Do any monster powers recharge on 2?

Tags: dnd-4e

As per [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/28229/559), certain monster powers in D&D 4e recharge on a certain result on 1d6. The lowest I've seen is Recharge 3-6, although the rules suggest 2-6 is possible.

Out of curiosity, do any creatures recharge a power on 2-6?

Answer (score 7):

I have never seen one in the official monster list, but it is not a searchable field in the online tools.

A recharge on 2+ is not much different to a slightly unreliable At Will. Although technically possible, most monster designers probably wouldn't bother, it's an extra roll each round that might make a difference typically on 1 turn of a combat.

I should add: Technically this is also true of *Recharge 6*, but there is a different, and more enjoyable interaction with the player characters in that case. A Recharge 6 power is usually designed to be more powerful than the monster's At Wills, and the players will feel the need to target a monster with a strong power that "might come back next round". Whereas a power that monster nearly always has available, and is only sometimes missing doesn't really drive the behaviour of PCs in combat.

Comment: Good analysis there.

Answer (score 3):

**No...**

This is in no way a super-firm answer but I just looked at the compendium at monsters above level 30 (the ones I would most expect to have insane recharges) and I can't find any that recharge on a roll of a 2. Unfortunately searching recharge 2 in the compendium is no different from searching recharge and brings up roughly 2.5k hits as the results in the creatures section.

Comment: Try checking just elites & solos; normals & minions almost never have recharge powers, much less recharge powers with a good range.

Comment: I was actually doing just that, the widest spread I saw was the 3-6 that he mentioned, please post and prove me wrong if you know of one though, I did not do an incredibly thorough search.